# piping stderr and stdout separately

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to do different things to the stdout and stderr of a particular command. Something like

```
cmd |1 stdout_1 | stdout_2 |2 stderr_1 | stderr_2
```

where stdout_x is a command specifically for stdout and stderr_x is specifically for stderr. It's okay if stderr from *every* command gets piped into my stderr commands, but it's even better if the stderr could be strictly from `cmd`. I've been searching for some syntax that may support this, but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of a **different file descriptor**:

```
{ cmd 2>&3 | stdout_1; } 3>&1 1>&2 | stderr_1
```

**Example:**

```
{ { echo 'out'; echo >&2 'error'; } 2>&3 | awk '{print "stdout: " $0}'; } 3>&1 1>&2 |
  awk '{print "stderr: " $0}'
stderr: error
stdout: out
```

Or else use **process substitution**:

```
cmd 2> >(stderr_1) > >(stdout_1)
```

**Example:**

```
{ echo 'out'; echo >&2 'error'; } 2> >(awk '{print "stderr: " $0}') \
> >(awk '{print "stdout: " $0}')
stderr: error
stdout: out
```

to pipe stdout and stderr **separately** from your `cmd`.

Comment: So what comes out of stderr_1 in either of your demonstrations is in plain-old stdout, right?

Comment: Check my example above where stdout and stderr remain independent in whole command line.

Comment: Right, I'm assuming the same goes for process substitution then?

Comment: Is __process substitution__ order dependent? i.e. `cmd 2> >(stderr_1) > >(stdout_1)` <==> `cmd > >(stdout_1) 2> >(stderr_1)`?

Comment: Yes it is **order dependent** otherwise output of `stderr_1` also gets piped into `stdout_1`. So better to pipe stderr first and stdout later. (as shown above)

Comment: You should note that **process substitution** is not **POSIX**. Also, what is the difference between `{ cmd ; }` and `( cmd )`? It seems that `{ cmd ; }` is slower... So, can I use `( cmd 2>&3 | stdout_1 ) 3>&1 1>&2 | stderr_1` instead of `{ cmd 2>&3 | stdout_1; } 3>&1 1>&2 | stderr_1`? Anyway, you saved my day. Thank you ;)

Comment: `( cmd )` actually runs `cmd` in a sub-shell whereas `{ cmd; }` runs in current shell itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use process substitution and redirection to achieve this:

```
cmd 2> >(stderr_1 | stderr_2) | stdout_1 | stdout_2
```

Comment: So what comes out of stderr_2 in either is in plain-old stdout, right?

Comment: Yes, once the output hits `stderr_1` as input, it's back to a normal pipeline.

Comment: Does the output of `stderr_2` then go into `stdout_1`?

Comment: Yes, after the stderr pipeline is over, it goes to stdout. But you can redirect to a file or /dev/null if you don't want it there

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution would be something like this:

```
(cmd | gets_stdout) 2>&1 | gets_stderr
```

The main drawback being that if `gets_stdout` itself has any output on stdout, that will also go to `gets_stderr`.   If that is a problem, you should use one of anubhava's or Kevin's answers.

Comment: If the standard output from `gets_stdout` isn't meant to go to `gets_stderr`, redirect its standard output to a file, or `/dev/null` if you really don't want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Late-answer - as with all previous answers stderr is landing in stdout at the end (@anubhava's answer was *nearly* complete).

To pipe stderr and stdout independently (or identical) and keep them in stdout and stderr, we can use file descriptors.

**Solution**:

```bash
{ { cmd | stdout_pipe ; } 2>&1 1>&3 | stderr_pipe; } 1>&2 3>&1
```

**Explanation**:

- piping in the shell always happens on stdout (file descriptor 1)
- we therefore apply the pipe for stdout directly (leaving stderr intact)
- then we park stdout in a temporary file descriptor and move stderr to stdout, allowing us to pipe this in the next step
- at the end we get the "current" stdout (piped stderr) back to stderr and stdout back from our temporary file descriptor

**Example**:

using

cmd = `{ echo 'out'; echo >&2 'error'; }`
stdout_pipe = `awk '{print "stdout: " $0}'`
stderr_pipe = `awk '{print "stderr: " $0}'`

```bash
{ { { echo 'out'; echo >&2 'error'; } \
  | awk '{print "stdout: " $0}'; } 2>&1 1>&3 \
  | awk '{print "stderr: " $0}'; } 1>&2 3>&1
```

**Note**: this example has an extra pair of `{ }` to "combine" both echo commands into a single one

You see the difference when redirecting the output of a script using this or when using this with a terminal that colors stderr.