# Processing stdout and stderr separately adding a timestamp: Wrong order

Tags: linux, bash, unix, docker, unix-timestamp

These are my test files:

`std-test.sh:`

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..20}
do
    number=$RANDOM
    let "number %= 10"
    if [ $number -le 6 ]
    then
        echo $i;
    else
        echo $i 1>&2;
    fi
done
```

`process.sh:`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    [[ $1 = "err" ]] && echo "$(date +%s%3N) $line" >> stderr;
    [[ $1 = "out" ]] && echo "$(date +%s%3N) $line" >> stdout;
done
```

`std-test.sh` creates twenty lines containing their line number, and `process.sh` is able to read another commands output when piped to it, while it saves to `stderr` when `err` is passed to it as argument, and to `stdout` when `out` is passed. The command I use to test the whole thing is:
`./std-test.sh 2> >(./process.sh err) > >(./process.sh out)` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27673635/7518929)). My test outputs are as follows:

`stdout:`

```
1486297129986 0
1486297129987 1
1486297129988 2
1486297129988 3
1486297129989 4
1486297129990 6
1486297129991 7
1486297129991 8
1486297129992 9
1486297129993 10
1486297129993 11
1486297129994 12
1486297129995 14
1486297129995 17
1486297129996 18
```

`stderr:`

```
1486297129986 5
1486297129987 13
1486297129987 15
1486297129988 16
1486297129989 19
1486297129990 20
```

When I tried parsing the output, I realized, that the order of `stderr` and `stdout` is completely messed up. Why does 5 in `stderr` come before 1 in `stdout`, for instance? Or 13 right after 1? What's the mistake I made here, and how could I resolve it?

**Edit #1:** I know I could pipe stderr and stdout directly to files, but `process.sh` will curl the results to a remote server. Saving it to files is just kind of a POC.

**Edit #2:** I am actually trying to timestamp and process docker logs programmatically.

Comment: I think it's a problem of flushing. stderr and stdout might not be flushed directly after echo. It seems that stderr is always flushed immediately, while stdout is flushed only when the buffer is full. See for example https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

From the comments it appears OP was really trying to timestamp and log the output from an application running in a docker container.

`docker logs -t` already does this and is the best tool for job.

---

Original answer:

Probably because you're timestamping each line with the time it is processed and not the time they're actually generated?

You launch 3 processes when you run that command, not all of them run in parallel.

The processes aren't running in a truly parallel fashion, they can get preempted whenever the kernel feels like. Because the stdout is longer/processing more lines, it is more likely to get preempted and then resumed at a later point. Which would explain the timestamping.

What do you really need the timestamps on the lines for? Do you simply want ordering between the lines, or do you want real true timestamps?

Edit: as @Sven Festersen pointed out in the comments, it also might be because [stdout is buffered when piped by default](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering).

Comment: I need real true timestamps. I will be running a docker container programmatically, catching the logs and storing them in a database, that can be queried using a web interface, which shows every line next to a formatted timestamp, coloring every stderr output red.

Comment: @BenjaminLaib In that case, you might want to leverage what docker already offers. You can use `docker logs --timestamps` to get the logs of your application from docker, pre-timestamped. That's likely does what you want and is probably more robust.

Comment: Oh thank you really much! I didn't know this option existed.

Comment: @BenjaminLaib can you please edit your question to reflect that you were trying to do this for docker and add the docker tag as well? Thanks!